# Incorrect Models passed to View MVC C# error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Can anyone help me correct the issue im having creating a view in MVC.  Normally i just use Add/View and it scaffolds a view for me based upon my created method.  The only problem is that this time i am creating a method to pass to view and i keep getting this error message

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'UserJob', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[UserJob]'.
```

The Methods i have written are the following...

```
public ActionResult AddJob(string userCode)
{
    var jobs = jobsClient.GetAlljobs();
    var alljobsCode = (from s in jobs select s.jobCode).ToList();
    var usersJobs = (from s in db.UserJobs
                               where s.userCode == userCode
                               select s.jobCode).ToList();
    var jobsNeeded = alljobsCode.Except(usersJobs);
    List<UserJobsDTO> list = listBuilder(jobs, jobsNeeded);
    ViewBag.jobCode = new SelectList(list, "jobCode", "jobDescription");
    var model = new UserJob { userCode = userCode };
    return View("AddJob", model);
}

private List<UserJobsDTO> listBuilder(
               jobsService.jobsDTO[] jobs, IEnumerable<string> jobsNeeded)
{
    List<UserJobsDTO> d = new List<UserJobsDTO>();

    var f = jobsNeeded.ToArray();
    var a = jobs.ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
    {
        d.Add(new UserJobsDTO()
        {
            jobCode = f.ElementAt(i),
            description = a[i].jobDescription
        });
    }             
        return d;
}
```

When im debugging all of the required data is being passed to all the correct variable i am declaring, but the view just isnt playing ball.  I was under the impression that scaffolding would automatically generate a useable View for me in Razor?? But this method just want play.  Can anyone point me in the right direction??

Comment: Don't you think the error message is _self explanatory_? You are passing a single UserJob object using `var model = new UserJob { userCode = userCode };` but the view expects a collection of UserJob.

Comment: I only want one passing through, but if i change this line of code in the Razor `@model IEnumerable<UserJob>`  to just this line of code `@model UserJob `  It produces this error message   `CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'UserJob ' because 'UserJob'  does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: That's pretty obvious too. When you don't have a collection itself then why you are trying to iterate over it using _foreach_ loop?

Comment: Thats just what the Scaffolding produced.  I guess it would just iterate the once. Would i need to write the Razor myself to get the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Corrected version

```
   public ActionResult AddJob(string userCode)
{
    var jobs = jobsClient.GetAlljobs();
    var alljobsCode = (from s in jobs select s.jobCode).ToList();
    var usersJobs = (from s in db.UserJobs
                               where s.userCode == userCode
                               select s.jobCode).ToList();
    var jobsNeeded = alljobsCode.Except(usersJobs);
    List<UserJobsDTO> list = listBuilder(jobs, jobsNeeded);
    ViewBag.jobCode = new SelectList(list, "jobCode", "jobDescription");
//    var model = new UserJob { userCode = userCode };
    return View("AddJob", usersJobs );
}
```

you will need to pass ienumarable here not an object type.

Update

```
@model IEnumerable<UserJobs> 

foreach(var item in Model){
   <span>@item.JobId</span>
    <span>@item.JobName</span>

}
```

Comment: I know that there will only be one userCode as its unique, so would i not want to have the single `var model = new UserJob` in there?  As i am adding jobs to a single userCode

Comment: On a side note, it is better practice to delcare 'model' as type UserJob because you KNOW that it definitely will be of type UserJob.

Comment: if you want single UserCode you have to change the model to @model UserJob

Comment: If i change to a `@model UserJob` It produces this error message `CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'UserJob ' because 'UserJob' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: well you can't iterate on that.try to pass ViewBag.UserJobs=someienumerablemodel for this foreach loop. if you want multiple models in your view.